# Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-props, react-component

I'm trying to build my First reactjs site, protfolio project, Right now I'm at the skills section.
I made a Skill file of an array of objects of my skills so that I could use map funtion in my Skills.jsx components and in fututre I could just add another skill object and map() will render it.
Once done with the the array of objects my site was rendering but all of a sudden I got this error!!

```
//My Skills.jsx: Once I render this I will use props for the map function.
import React from "react";
function Skills() {
  return (
    <>
      <section className="skills">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="content">
            <img src="./src/assets/html5.svg" alt="htmlIcon" />
            <p>HTML</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}
export default Skills;
//My Skills JSON: (I have 10 objects in it.)

const skills = [
  {
    id: 1,
    icon: "./src/assets/html5.svg",
    iconName: "HTML",
  },
 ];
export default skills;
```

I want to render the Skill JSON obect in my Skills.jsx component using map function!!

Comment: We be useful to see how you import this, but I presume your are mixing `Skills` (uppercase) and `skills` (lowercase)... I guess you are importing the array and you pretend to use it as a react component.

This link can be useful for you as well https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-element-type-is-invalid-expected-string-but-got

Comment: I have added the necessary files in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-architecture-qyzw0w?file=/src/App.js                                                                         Site is working there but not in my local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the Map function, and I have successfully implemented it now all that is left is styling it!!

```
//Skills.jsx:
import React from "react";

function Skills(props) {
   return (
    <>
      <section className="skills">
        <div className="card">
          Skills
          <div className="content">
            <img src={props.icon} alt="htmlIcon" />
            <p>{props.iconName}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default Skills;

//App.jsx:
import React from "react";
import Skills from "./Skills";
import skills from "./Skill";
import Footer from "./Footer";

function addSkill(skill) {
  return (
     <Skills
      key={skill.id}
      id={skill.id}
      icon={skill.icon}
      iconName={skill.iconName}
    />
  );
}
function App(){
      return(
       <>
         {skills.map(addSkill)}
       </>
      );
}
export default App;
```